# How to do OR Queries and Regex Queries using JsonPath

Tags: java, json

I just tried out `JsonPath` for some Application level Filtering and found out
that i coud not do an `OR` Query , `RegeX` Query.

Is it Possible to do such queries using `JsonPath`? If not can u suggest some other libraries
to do the same.